# repo gets stuck after downloading

Tags: android, repository

I'm using repo to download Android source code (ICS). However, repo gets stuck after downloading about 6.2G data. The last lines of repo's output is:

```
remote: Counting objects: 249, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (129/129)
remote: Getting sizes: 100% (144/144)
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24/24)
remote: Total 129 (delta 69), reused 127 (delta 68)
Receiving objects: 100% (129/129), 15.60 MiB | 2.17 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (69/69), completed with 46 local objects.
From https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilt
 * [new branch]      ics-factoryrom-2-release -> aosp/ics-factoryrom-2-release
 * [new branch]      ics-mr0    -> aosp/ics-mr0
 * [new branch]      ics-mr0-release -> aosp/ics-mr0-release
 * [new branch]      ics-mr1    -> aosp/ics-mr1
 * [new branch]      ics-mr1-release -> aosp/ics-mr1-release
   367f94c..3929228  master     -> aosp/master
 * [new tag]         android-2.2.3_r1 -> android-2.2.3_r1
 * [new tag]         android-2.2.3_r2 -> android-2.2.3_r2
 * [new tag]         android-4.0.1_r1 -> android-4.0.1_r1
 * [new tag]         android-4.0.1_r1.1 -> android-4.0.1_r1.1
 * [new tag]         android-4.0.1_r1.2 -> android-4.0.1_r1.2
 * [new tag]         android-4.0.2_r1 -> android-4.0.2_r1
 * [new tag]         android-4.0.3_r1 -> android-4.0.3_r1
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.2_r8 -> android-cts-2.2_r8
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.3_r10 -> android-cts-2.3_r10
 * [new tag]         android-cts-2.3_r11 -> android-cts-2.3_r11
 * [new tag]         android-cts-4.0_r1 -> android-cts-4.0_r1
 * [new tag]         android-cts-verifier-4.0_r1 -> android-cts-verifier-4.0_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-4.0.3-tools_r1 -> android-sdk-4.0.3-tools_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-4.0.3_r1 -> android-sdk-4.0.3_r1
 * [new tag]         android-sdk-adt_r16.0.1 -> android-sdk-adt_r16.0.1
```

Then no response for quite a while (>1 hour). Really don't know what has happened. du the folder shows its size doesn't change. No network traffic any more. Should I wait or kill repo and restart? The previous trial was also like this...Looking for an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. Kill it and restart. This does no harm when doing repo sync. The size of the whole repository is more than 6G. I guess the stuck was due to some network problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on the same line! I think that one is systemic:

android-sdk-adt_r16.0.1 -> android-sdk-adt_r16.0.1

After killing the process the following error appeared, even with sync -f :
Fetching projects:   0% (1/262)  fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/rodrigo/open-projects/droid/.repo/projects/bionic.git'

So I simply did a rm over '/home/rodrigo/open-projects/droid/.repo/projects/bionic.git', I know its an Orc solution but worked... code was downloaded.