# curl 56 error on Android Studio GitHub repo clone

Tags: android, git, github

When I clone my project from GitHub by Android studio, this problem happened:

```
clone curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806 
The remote end hung up unexpectedly early EOF 
index-pack failed
```

I have googled many ways to solve, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try at least, as in [this answer, to kill and restart the process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8718372/6309).
Sometimes, it is enough.

But... it could be a network issue, considering your are in China (see the comments [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20835507/6309))

The [OP Dale.Che](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7556675/dale-che) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42431693/curl-56-error-on-android-studio-github-repo-clone/42448488?noredirect=1#comment72045515_42448488) having cloned the repo through Git itself, in command line (`git clone`).

Comment: yeah,I am really in China... Finally, I cloned it by " git clone". But I still don't know why it didn't work on Android studio.

Comment: @Dale.Che OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.